# Dojo/on. emits, widget.on etc. in Dojo 1.8/2.0

Tags: dojo

I would like to gain a full understanding of how events work in Dojo. I am actually interested in the way Dojo 2.0 works -- I am using 1.8 now, but I am only really interested in using/documenting features that will *not* be deprecated for 2.0. 
Now... in _WidgetBase.js I read:

```
on: function(/*String|Function*/ type, /*Function*/ func){
  // For backwards compatibility, if there's an onType() method in the widget then connect to that.
                // Remove in 2.0.
```

This basically means that in the near future a widget's on will basically do:

```
  on: function(/*String|Function*/ type, /*Function*/ func){
            // Otherwise, just listen for the event on this.domNode.
            return this.own(on(this.domNode, type, func))[0];
```

Which is fine. Now... in the release note for 1.8, I see:

"Widget events, including attribute changes, are emitted as events on the DOM tree"

The release note point to this: http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/quickstart/events#widget-events-published-to-the-dom Which "sort of" explain things, although the document seems to be outdated (it still talks about aspect for "plain object").

So, my question: is there a spot/bunch of pages/tickets that would describe the current *updated* way in which the whole events thing works?

My current understanding (for Dojo 2.0):

- on: 100% delegated to on.js
- emit: when you run randomWidget.on('something', function(){}): 
  -if randomWidget has 'onsomething', it will simply run that; <--- will this go away with 2.0? 
  -Otherwise, it will delegate to on()

So, it's all about understanding dojo/on. That's when I get confused: reading the source code, on.js seems to delegate functionality to the widget itself (which... I just wrote above, will simply delegate to dojo/on from 2.0...?!?). Unless the bit that delegates to the object is destined to disappear...?

Also, I am used to writing widgets with templates, and then add  items where I do data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_click" where I make sure a function is called when somebody clicks on it. With the new on() system, will this change? (I mean, is all events propagates to DOM, is the opposite also true?)

So, can somebody shed some light on this? I feel a little uneasy at the moment, adding events and doing things, because I am not 100% sure of what is going on.

Thank you!

Comment: Yeah it's true some stuff are going to change. What I do currently is just use dojo/on for my events and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gosh that was a while ago...
Since then, I wrote this:

https://github.com/mercmobily/writeups/blob/master/dojo/widgets_containers_on.md

Which explains pretty much the whole lot!

Merc.